# Updating a Table View From a Different File - Cannot invoke 'reloadData' with no arguments

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to refresh a Table View from a different file. I've been trying to use `.reloadData()`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code...

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Alert
    func showAddAlert() {

        print("Show Add Alert to User")

        //Create a new alert
        let addAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Company", message: addAlertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        //Create the actions for the alert
        let yesAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            portfolio1.append(self.newCompany)
            print("User added company")
            print(portfolio1)
            StockTableViewController.tableView.reloadData() // Cannot invoke 'reloadData' with no arguments
        })

        let noAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            print("User canceled action")
            self.counter++
        })

        //Add the actions to be alert
        addAlert.addAction(noAlert)
        addAlert.addAction(yesAlert)

        //Present it to the user
        self.presentViewController(addAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Present Alert
    showAddAlert()
}
```

And here are my files...

```
AppDelegate.swift
StockTableViewController.swift
GraphViewControllerViewController.swift // - (where the code is from)
Main.storyboard
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do instead is implement local notifcations or KVO so that your `TableView` knows when it needs to be reloaded, and then reload it from within the proper file according to when the notification is received.