# Swift Refresh TableView after creation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

In swift I have two view controllers. One is a tableView and displays data from an array. On a function call the other view controller calls the tableView and delivers arguments with new data for the table view. Even when I update the array `buckets` where the data is taken from the TableView doesn't update. How do I get the program to reload its data?

**TABLE VIEW**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class BucketTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var buckets = ["A", "B", "C"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return buckets.count
    } 
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = buckets[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func updateBuckets(newBucket: NSArray) {
        buckets = newBucket as! [String]
        self.tableView?.reloadData()
    } 
}
```

I can verify that updateBuckets is called from the other view controller.

**OTHER VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
    var bigArray = ["M", "A", "R", "C"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let buckets = BucketTableViewController()
    buckets.updateBuckets(bigArray)

}
```

Comment: Have you checked, that the tableView already exists at the time you call updateBuckets?

Comment: @freytag I just threw the updateBuckets in a delayed method and that didn't change the outcome. So yes, the tableView is already created

Comment: Did you checked that tableView's delegate and dataSource is not nil's?

Answer (score 5):

Try using `tableView?.beginUpdates()` and `tableView?.endUpdates()` instead - I've found that `tableView?.reloadData()` can be finicky about data source updates sometimes.

Otherwise, make sure you're calling `updateBuckets()` on the right instance of `BucketTableViewController()`; it looks like you instantiated a new instance in your viewDidLoad() instead of changing the content of an existing instance (as you presumably would be doing).

Comment: `reloadData()` is guaranteed to work. If it doesn't work, something is very seriously broken.

Comment: If nothing else is wrong, yes it will always work - this case seems simple enough, I agree.  The error is probably that OP called updateBuckets() on the wrong instance of BucketTableViewController().

Comment: @KevinZhang I create an instance of BucketTableViewController() in the class and reference that in my calls. How can I access the tableview class without creating a new one?

Comment: @KevinZhang If I remove the BucketTableViewController() then I can't called updateBuckets. [I think] I need to instantiate a variable first

Comment: Where are you displaying the table view controller?  In the view controller that displays the table view, you should store a public variable keeping track of the table view controller, then modify that instance.

Comment: If you're trying to display a BucketTableViewController in your "Other View Controller", declare a variable property in the class as such:

`class OtherViewController: UIViewController {
        var bucketTableView: BucketTableViewController = BucketTableViewController()
        let bigArray = ["M", "A", "R", "C"]

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            bucketTableView.updateBuckets(bigArray)
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

This line right here:

```
let buckets = BucketTableViewController()
```

You're creating a brand new `BucketTableViewController` instance and updating its buckets. That's not going to cause the existing `BucketTableViewController` to update. You need to figure out how to get a reference to the existing view controller and update it instead.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some help in "figur[ing] out how to get a reference to the existing view controller"

Answer (score -1):

I would reccomend the same thing for you as I did in this answer here: [Updating a Table View From a Different File - Cannot invoke 'reloadData' with no arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274878/updating-a-table-view-from-a-different-file-cannot-invoke-reloaddata-with-no)